# Unable to load bootstrap on webpage after implementing spring security

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap

I am using spring boot with the bootstrap dependency. After implementing a portion of code I am unable to load my webpage with bootstrap (the page will load but it will not utilize bootstrap). I am using the spring bootstrap dependency. Anyone have similar results using spring boot and thymeleaf?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers().permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

Comment: Can you post your security config?

Comment: Hard to say with so little information but I don't think it's related to Spring Security. Have you setup your MVC (in case you're using it) to server your assets?

Comment: Is that overriding the addViewControllers method? I have done that yes. But I only have an addViewController for every webpage that I have in the application nothing else.

Comment: I have added the security configuration class

Comment: sorry pheraps I don't undertand well the problem. the keypoint was that the your pages don't be able to use twitter bootstrap css framework?

Comment: Correct, the bootstrap does not render after implementing the spring security code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem if reportet to css I use a configuration like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true,prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http....
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(LOG_IN_URL_PAGE,
                        LOG_OUT_URL_PAGE,
                        "/css/**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/**/favicon.ico",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/signup").permitAll()
                             .antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                             .anyRequest().authenticated();
     }

     ...

     }
```

webjars dependency in my pom

```
<!--static assets-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>select2</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>select2-bootstrap-css</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

I use a configuration like this in a my open source projects and works for me

the key point is that you have say at Spring Secuirty that don't secure the resource url

for the resorce url Spring boot autoconfiguration make the work for you it is the motivation of webjars as sample of usage

you can see the complete set of avaiable webjars at the link http://www.webjars.org/

I hope that this can help you

Comment: if you are interest at the complete configuration you can see the link https://github.com/mrFlick72/socialDocumentLibrary at the user-documentlibrary-client part